# Should I test toString() with junit?

Tags: java, junit, tostring

Can such tests have a good reason to exist?

Comment: No, it is not. There are probably more important things to test.

Comment: I though it would be a good idea to test it. Simply at a later date somebody using your class may wish to include it in a log file or use it for debugging purposes. Do you wish them to have to figure out why this method is not working as expected?

Comment: Only when the documentation [JavaDoc] makes any promises about the String content because then it is part of the (public) API and other code may rely on it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some classes use `toString` for more than just user-readable informative string. Examples are `StringBuilder` and `StringWriter`. In such a case it is of course advisable to test the method just like any other business-value method.

Even in the general case it is good practice to smoke-test `toString` for reliability (no exceptions thrown). The last thing you need is a log statement blowing up your code due to an ill-implemented `toString`. It has happened to me several times, and the resulting bugs are of the nastiest kind, since you don't even see the `toString` call in the source code—it's implicitly buried inside a log statement.

Answer (score 4):

The question is not should I test toString(), but do you care about the result of toString()? Is it used for something? If so, then yes, test it.

If a method gets used for something real, then test it.

Comment: If toString() is not used for anything, it shouldn't even be implemented.

Comment: @HeikoSchmitz To clarify, I meant that if the implementation changes it has an effect on the program, so if it is used as a key into a map, or such. In this case, you need a test for it. However, toString() is used when you're logging an object, but this should not change the program behaviour if the implementation changes. In this case, you shouldn't need a test for it. Except for the caveat mentioned by Marko, when the toString() crashes while logging, of course.

Comment: OK, I agree. However, (ab)using toString() to generate a map key is probably bad style anyway.

Comment: @HeikoSchmitz re: Using toString() for a map key, completely agree that it is not good, it was just an example.

Answer (score 3):

Obvious answer is „no, it's just a waste of time“. But for many classes, first of all value-wrappers, toString should be overloaded and deliver more information that just org.package.ClassName@2be2befa

So my propostal test for toString is:

```
@Test
public final void testToString() {
    assertFalse(new MyClass().toString().contains("@"));
}
```

It also increases test converage what is at least not bad.

Comment: Tests should be there to test relevant business logic, not just to increase test coverage.

Comment: Yes, and i just test wheather the default implementation is overloaded to deliver some meaningfull info or not. Using reflection to call super.toString() is possible too.

Comment: @Jesper - Unit tests are not for testing business logic. Unit tests are there it check that a particular implementation of a class is behaving as expected. There are other tests for business logic (integration, system etc).

Answer (score 0):

If the result of the method is important to you, you should test it, otherwise you can just ignore that.

Comment: I'd like to ignore it, but damn code coverage requires to test it :c

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go against the general advise and say testing a toString method definitely has its place. Applications I have work on log a lot, especially if you turn on debug or trace level logs. If I am relying on the logs to help identify a bug and some fields from my POJO are not present because some developer forgot to regenerate the toString method, this is a huge setback!

The problem is that the toString method is an absolute pain to test as their is no fixed format or a clear way to test it. I would recommend not writing a test yourself, but using a library such as [ToStringVerifier](https://github.com/jparams/to-string-verifier)

```
@Test
public void testToString()
{
    ToStringVerifier.forClass(User.class).verify();
}
```